# Exact sequences, mostly linear algebra and notation confusion.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> **Problem**: Let $0 \to A^0\stackrel{d^0}{\to} A^1 \stackrel{d^1}{\to} \dots \stackrel{d^{n-1}}{\to} A^n \to 0  $ be a chain complex and assume each $A^i$ is finite-dimensional. Prove that the sequence
>   $$0 \to H^i(A^*) \to \frac{A^i}{Im(d^{i-1})} \stackrel{d^i}{\to} Im(d^{i}) \to 0 $$ is also exact. where $H^i(A^*) = \frac{Ker(d: \Omega^{p}(A^*) \to \Omega^{p+1}(A^*))}{Im(d: \Omega^{p-1}(A^*) \to \Omega^{p}(A^*))}$ where $A^* = (A^i, d^i)$ is precisely 
>   $$0 \to A^0\stackrel{d^0}{\to} A^1 \stackrel{d^1}{\to} \dots \stackrel{d^{n-1}}{\to} A^n \to 0  $$

The key says,

> [image]

**Q1**: Why is the induced quotient map $\frac{Ker(d^i)}{Im(d^{i-1})} \to \frac{A^i}{Im(d^{i-1})}$ the inclusion map? No where does it say this really is the inclusion map.

**Q2**: Looks like $d^i$ is just a regular homomoprhism, it is not surjective, so why do they say $x = d^i(y)$?

**Q3**: What does "$d^{i}([x]) = d^i(x)$" even mean? The notations are confusing. How can a set $[x]$ equal an element $x$? Not to mention, I don't feel like they proved the subjectivity of $d^i$ at all…they just stated the definition. I can understand the exactness in the middle once I understand the notations.(answered) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It's not necessarily true that $\frac{\ker(d^i)}{\text{Im}(d^{i-1})} \supseteq  \frac{A^i}{\text{Im}(d^{i-1})}$, and we don't need this.  The unlabeled map $\frac{\ker(d^i)}{\text{Im}(d^{i-1})} \to \frac{A^i}{\text{Im}(d^{i-1})}$ is supposed to be an inclusion, so it suffices to check that $\ker(d^i) \subseteq A^i$, since this inclusion will descend to the quotient.

2) $x$ is an element of $A^i$, while $[x]$ is an element of $A^i/\text{Im}(d^i)$, i.e., a coset $x + \text{Im}(d^i)$.  So in order to define $d^i : A^i/\text{Im}(d^i) \to \text{Im}(d^i)$ by $d^i([x]) = d^i(x)$, we need to ensure that this definition is independent of the representative we choose for the coset $x + \text{Im}(d^i)$.

3) Technically, the $d^i$ on the left is not the same map as the $d^i$ on the right.  The one on the left is a map $d^i : A^i/\text{Im}(d^i) \to \text{Im}(d^i)$ that we want to define, while the one on the right is $d^i : A^i \to A^{i+1}$.  This is sloppy notation, but understandable considering how many maps we have lying around.  Maybe we should call the map on the quotient $\overline{d^i} : A^i/\text{Im}(d^i) \to \text{Im}(d^i)$ and say that we want to define $\overline{d^i}$ by $\overline{d^i}([x]) = d^i(x)$.

Here is how their proof shows $\overline{d^i}$ is well-defined.  Take a coset $[x] = x + \text{Im}(d^{i-1})$ and suppose we pick a different representative $y$ for this coset.  Then $x + \text{Im}(d^{i-1}) = y + \text{Im}(d^{i-1})$, so $x - y + \text{Im}(d^{i-1}) =\text{Im}(d^{i-1})$, hence $x = y + d^{i-1}(z)$ for some $z \in A^{i-1}$.  They show that $d^i(x) = {d^i}(y + d^{i-1}(z))$ and ${d^i}(y)$ are the same, hence the value we get is independent of the choice of representative for a coset.  Thus the map $\overline{d^i}$ defined by $\overline{d^i}(x + \text{Im}(d^{i-1}) = d^i(x)$ is well-defined.

Comment: If $B \subseteq X$, then the inclusion $i : B \to X$ is just the map sending $b \in B$ to $b \in X$.  It's just the identity map restricted to $B$.  So the first map is just supposed to be $k + \text{Im}(d^i) \in \ker(d^i)/\text{Im}(d^i)$ maps to $k+\text{Im}(d^i)$ in $A^i + \text{Im}(d^i)$.  You have a map $d^i$ and you're trying to define the map $\overline{d^i}$.

As for your second comment, you seemed unclear on what $d^i([x])$ means versus $d^i(x)$.  Since these are different functions, I thought calling them different names would clarify.

Comment: (1) It is supposed to be so obvious that this map is the inclusion that they don't even write it.  You have a subset $\ker(d^i) \subseteq A^i$.  What injective map $\ker(d^i) \to A^i$ could be easier to define than the inclusion?

Comment: (1) but we are trying to *prove* injectivity. How do we know this really is the inclusion map? I am trying to say that this is circular logic.

Comment: Yes you are trying to prove injectivity, but you are supposed to already know what the map $H^i(A^*) \to A^i/\text{Im}(d^{i-1})$ is, namely the map induced by the inclusion.  How could you possibly prove injectivity if you don't even know what the map is?  The inclusion map $\ker(d^i) \hookrightarrow A^i$ is certainly injective.  You should prove the induced map $\ker(d^i)/\text{Im}(d^{i-1}) \to A^i/\text{Im}(d^{i-1})$ is also injective.

Comment: I edited the answer to address your question about (3).

Comment: Thanks you cleared up a lot, so about (3), is the existence of $z \in A^{i-1}$ included in $d^i$? Because that's the only way i could see how they say "Let $x \in Im(d^i) \implies x = d^{i}(y)$ for some $y \in A^i$"

Comment: Actually $d^i$ is surjective because it is defined in terms of the wedge product.