# Is the induced map between quotient vector spaces automatically an inclusion?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T: V_1 \to V_2$ is a linear map and $W \subset V_1$ and $W \subset V_2$ with $T(W) \subset W$, then the (induced) map $T: \frac{V_1}{W} \to \frac{V_2}{W}$ given by $$T(x + W) = T(x) + T(W)$$ is well-defined (and possibly injective?)

I know that $T(W) \subset W$, we get for free, but how does one show $T(x) \subset W$ as well? I have no idea how to prove other inclusion.

This question was inspired by my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971073/exact-sequences-mostly-linear-algebra-and-notation-confusion).

Specifically, $d^i : A^i \to A^{i+1}$ where $0 \to A^0\stackrel{d^0}{\to} A^1 \stackrel{d^1}{\to} \dots \stackrel{d^{n-1}}{\to} A^n \to 0$

We want to define a map $$\frac{\ker(d^i:A^i\to A^{i+1})}{Im(d^{i-1} :A^{i-1} \to A^i )} \to \frac{A^i}{Im(d^{i-1}: A^{i-1} \to A^i)}$$

The most natural choice is $$T(x + Im(d^{i-1})) = T(x) + T(Im(d^{i-1}) )$$. It was commented that this map is injective (in fact an inclusion map), but it is not obvious to me why $Im(d^{i-1}) \subset T(x) + T(Im(d^{i-1}))$

Comment: Do you mean $T(W_1)\subset W_2$?

Comment: @curious, yes I did, I made several mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T:V_1/W \to V_2/W$ defined by
$$
T(X) = T(x) + T(W) \quad X \in V_1/W, \ x\in X.
$$
In order to prove that $T$ is well-defined, you have to prove that the value $T(X)$ for $X\in V_1/W$ does not depend on the choice of the representative $x\in X$.

First observe that
$$
T(x) + T(W) = [T(x)],
$$
i.e., it is the equivalence class of $T(x)$ in $V_2/W$.

Now let $X\in V_1/W$, $x_1,x_2\in X$ hence $x_1-x_2\in W$.
Then
$$
y:=T(x_1) - T(x_2) = T(x_1-x_2) \in T(W) \subset W.
$$
This implies that the equivalence classes in $V_2/W$ coincide
$$
[T(x_1)] = [T(x_2)].
$$
Since this holds for all $x_1,x_2\in X$, the value $T(X)$ is well-defined, as it does not depend on the concrete choice of the representative.

Comment: But why might this be injective? You showed $T(x) + T(W) \subset W$, but how does $W \subset T(x) + T(W)$?

Comment: This map should be injective if $T|_W$ is injective. Why should the other inclusions hold at all?

Comment: Because this is a subquestion from another question of mine where it must be that the other inclusion holds. Let me make edit, to clarify.